# How to read both xls and xlsx with Apache Poi library?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have an app that reads from an excel. The problem is that I only can read xlsx files. I cant read xls files. This is my code:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)+"/"+nomeExcel));
                        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
                        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                        int rowCtr = 34;
                        Row myRow = sheet.getRow(rowCtr++);
                        while (myRow != null) {
                            Cell nif = myRow.getCell(0);
                            Cell marcaexploracao = myRow.getCell(1);
                            Cell numerochip = myRow.getCell(2);
                            Cell marcaauricular = myRow.getCell(3);
                            Cell datanascimento = myRow.getCell(4);

                            bd.addAnimais(numerochip.toString().replace("\u00a0",""),marcaexploracao.toString().trim(),marcaauricular.toString(),datanascimento.toString(),nif.toString(),0,"","","","",0);
                            myRow = sheet.getRow(rowCtr++);
                        }

                    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Excel importado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
```

Comment: Apache POI has seperate package to read XLSX, Instead of HSSFWorkbook use XSSFWorkbook etc.This link may be useful - http://www.java67.com/2014/09/how-to-read-write-xlsx-file-in-java-apache-poi-example.html

Comment: XSSF can read both of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `Workbook` with `WorkbookFactory.create` method like that:

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.xls"));
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

Comment: Can I use StringValue of in new FIleIputStream?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The first error while copy your code is: Cannot resolve constructor in new FileInputStream. After that I trie to use stringValueOf and resolves the issue. But then it gives me a org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: when I read the excel xls.

Comment: It works for me bue only with xlsx excel files. I want both xls and xlsx :/

Comment: This exception could be if you don't have a file with such path or it may be empty. Can you check it in debug mode?

Comment: When I download the xls file my phone erases all cells and puts the document in blank. Can you have any ideia why?

Comment: Yeah... I don't have an idea about that, but did I help with something? :)

Comment: As the docs explain, [don't use an InputStream if you have a File, use the File directly!](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Answer (score 0):

For reading `xlsx` file 
`Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);`

For reading `xls` file (< 2007)
`Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);`

No other changes required.